# Snowflake UPDATE table and parameterize column to be updated

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a requirement to parameterize the column to be updated.
Trying to achieve something like this:

CODE SNIPPET:

set fVal = 'col1';

-- update query

UPDATE  as t1
SET
IDENTIFIER($fVal) = t2.value
from
<TABLE 2> as t2
where t1.id = t2.id
;

Snowflake throws error saying: **SQL compilation error: syntax error line 4 at position 14 unexpected '('.**

Comment: You can't use placeholders in a prepared statement for the column and table names.  You might need to rethink your approach here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can parameterize like this. If you have a requirement to dynamically generate a SQL statement, use Python or any other programming language. It is easier to do in Python. For templating, you can use Jinja2 package as below.I have hard coded the sql string inside Template, you can also read it from a file.

```
from jinja2 import Template

t = Template("UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET {{ COLNAME }} = 'WHATEVER'    ")
sql_query = t.render(COLNAME="EMPNAME")

print('Now execute my sql: ' + sql_query)
```

Comment: Thanks, Rajib, this seems to be the only way of doing it.

Comment: Let us know how you solve it finally. Also please accept the answer if it is the right one for you now